# Sitecore Debug Tool Question

Tags: caching

What is the difference between physical read and cache miss and how are these calculated in the Sitecore Debug tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through the implementation of the counters is looks like a cache miss is when an item is not found in cache and physical read is when Sitecore does a SQL call. I'm not 100% sure but it looks like cache miss is only considering ItemCache which would cause the numbers to be different.